# перевод обычной программы на c C++ на ассемблер

Tags: c++, ассемблер, g++

помогите,пожалуйста, разобрать код созданный в результате компиляции из C++ в ассемблер при помощи g++. Пытаюсь читать Брюса Эккеля. но видимо компиляторы давно шагнули вперед поэтому описание которое приведено в книге отлично от того, что получается при помощи g++.
Итак, вот элементарная программа :

```
int foo(int i) {
    return i+1;
}


int main() {
    int y = foo(20);
}
```

после выполнения:

```
g++ -E foo.cpp -o foo.ii
g++ -S foo.ii -o foo.s
```

имеем вот такой ассемблерный код:

```
    .file   "foo.cpp"
    .text
    .globl  __Z3fooi
    .def    __Z3fooi;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
__Z3fooi:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    popl    %ebp
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $20, (%esp)
    call    __Z3fooi
    movl    %eax, 28(%esp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE1:
    .ident  "GCC: (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0"
```

итак вот эти строки непонятны  :

1. в этой строке происходит задание параметра, верно ? :

```
    movl    $20, (%esp)
```

2. затем вызывается моя функция, её имя тут call __Z3fooi
   далее переносимся в функцию , вот тут совсем ничего не понятно:
3. зачем делать : `pushl  %ebp` ?
4. верно ли я понимаю, что таким образом мы заносим значение параметра в регистр esp    `movl %esp, %ebp`
   ?
5. зачем делается    `movl    8(%ebp), %eax` ?
6. как я понимаю  `addl   $1, %eax` это увеличивает на единицу нашу регистр ?
7. этим восстанавливается значе  `popl    %ebp`

может быть есть где почитать статьи как передается в функцию параметры и выполняются ?

Comment: Параметры в функцию передаются индивидуально компилятору и архитектуре процессора. В `gcc` решили что все аргументы передавать как можно больше через регистры *(если это проц аналогичен Intel/AMD)*. Компилятор `gcc` возвращаемое значаение передаёт в основном через регистр `eax` (если результат помещается).

Comment: Не целые числа передаются тоже через регистры , но сопроцессора ( если в процессоре такое имеется ). Например простая функция сложения типов `double` не будет трогать стек и регистр `eax`. Всё будет только через математический сопроцессор.

Answer (score 2):

```
movl    $20, (%esp)
```

esp - это указатель стека. это так изобретательно в стек заталкиваем параметр
pushl  %ebp

в ebp мы будем хранить указатель на стек до увеличения, но некрасиво просто так менять регистр, поэтому мы его запомним в стеке. А потом

```
movl %esp, %ebp
```

запишем esp в ebp (а предыдущее уже сохранено!)

```
movl    8(%ebp), %eax
```

а теперь берем 8 байтовое с стека - это наш параметр, который main туда положила.

```
addl    $1, %eax
```

делаем то, что нас попросили - +1

```
popl    %ebp
```

и восстановили регистр назад. Мы же его чуть выше попоритили.

а результат по соглашению возвращаем в eax - он уже там.

То есть, код делает ровно то, что его попросили.

Что бы не мучатся с ручной компиляцией, рекомендую сервис https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: `movl    8(%ebp), %eax` это `mov eax, [ebp + 8]`

Comment: да, давно я этот синтаксис не трогал

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо большое за отклик. возникла пара вопросов исходя из ответов по логике работы компилятора :1.не понятна что означает фраза  ```это так изобретательно в стек заталкиваем параметр pushl %ebp```.в ebp мы будем хранить указатель на стек до увеличения, но некрасиво просто так менять регистр, поэтому мы его запомним в стеке. 2. movl    8(%ebp),%eax - почему 8 байт???мы же int кладем , а это как правило 4 байта . можете вообще расписать общий принцип ?мы изначально сохраняем в стеке параметры , но сначала сохраняем туда вспомогательные регистры , чтобы потом их восстановить. верно ?

Comment: по половине вопроса - есть такое соглашение - что если функция собралась менять регистры, которые ей не предназначены, то она обязана их сохранить. А один из самых простых способов - это запихнуть в стек, а потом достать. Собственно это и происходит с ebp. А с 8 байтами я похоже поспешил немного. В первом комментарии подсказывают правильный вариант.